# expectation of supremum of random process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose $(X_{n}(t))_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of real valued stochastic processes, and $T>0$ a fixed number.

Suppose further that :
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\displaystyle{\sup_{n>0}}\ |X_n(t+h)-X_n(t)|\right]\leq c(h)
\end{equation}

with $\displaystyle{\lim_{h\to 0}}\ c(h)=0$

Do we have the following implication ?

$\displaystyle{ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{t\in[0,T]}} \mathbb{E}[|X_n(t)|] =0$ implies $\displaystyle{ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in[0,T]}}|X_n(t)|] =0$

Comment: Have a look here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76624/expectation-of-supremum

Comment: @TheBridge : thanks but there is no satisfactory answer so far